# Change browser URL information on hover with GWT

Tags: gwt

I would like to hide the information of a URL within my GWT application.  When a user mouses over a link the toolbar at the bottom of the browser displays the location.  In my opinion this is a security risk, I would like to override that information with some innocuous text.

This seems like something pretty straight forward, but I cannot find anything!

Comment: If you have a link, anyone can click (or middle-click/ctrl-click/drag'n'drop) on it and see the URL in the browser's address bar, or right-click and save directly as a bookmark or copy URL to the clipboard. As suggested by the answer you accepted, maybe you don't a link after all (but really, if there's a URL involved, it'll be visible somewhere, even if only the browser's developer tools; so I'd rather vote for @kae-verens' answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a href link, by default the browser shows the location at the bottom. To work around this, you can use some other Widget like label or menu item etc and write your own onClick listener, which would just take to the page you wanted the user to go.

Comment: I suppose that will have to suffice then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"In my opinion this is a security risk" - wrong. security through obscurity is no security at all.

at the best, it will keep people away that can't read source.

at the worst, the people that eventually hack your system will be better than amateur.

just make your system secure, and don't try to hide your URLs

Comment: You can't read GWT source because there is nothing to read, so by hiding the source then it will shield that information.

Comment: You can't hide JavaScript source. Yes, GWT compiles into a dense lump of JS, but this doesn't mean it's "secure" - just that it's hard to read. True security is done on the server-side, not the client-side.